# How would you compose a complex plugin with lots of routes and functions?

Tags: plugin-development

I’m used to working in application frameworks like CodeIgniter, where you have MVC separation and multiple controller classes

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some work to adapt the [WordPress-Plugin-Skeleton](https://github.com/iandunn/WordPress-Plugin-Skeleton) repo by Ian Dunn of Automattic (check out his [presentation on WordPress plugin MVC](https://iandunn.name/content/presentations/wp-oop-mvc/oop.php) - good stuff).

My repo is [arswright/wordpress-plugin-skeleton](https://github.com/arswright/wordpress-plugin-skeleton) though, unfortunately, I'm too wrapped up in my own plugin dev work (and lurking StackExchange) to finish porting over the dependency injection container, dispatcher, and form elements I've been working on just now... if you want to watch that repo, though, I'll have updates and some documentation within a few weeks.

**Edit:** Hopefully you found that link to Ian Dunn's work helpful in any case - though I figured it'd only take me a few minutes to integrate changes from active development, so that repo now reflects a hodge-podge of updates (use at your own risk or just copy what you like and scrap the rest).